# how do I have my discord bot go through a vpn?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a vpn based on vless and xtls-reality and Im on a network where discord is blocked. I can access discord normally through the app with my vpn but my discord.py bot does not connect to discord through my vpn and causes errors

I tried turning on my discord bot like normal while connected to my vpn, but since discord is blocked on my network like mentioned earlier, I got errors and I assumed that discord.py was not establishing a connection through my vpn